# Large deviations Exercise (Durret 2.7.6)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems, large-deviation-theory

I'm studying probability theory and doing the exercises in Durret v5.

> Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ iid with $EX_1 = 0$. Show that if $\epsilon,a>0$, then
> then  $$\liminf_{n\to\infty }\frac{P(S_n \geq na)}{nP(X_1 \geq
> n(a+\epsilon))}\geq 1$$
>
> Hint: Let $F_n =\{ X_i \geq n(a+\epsilon)
> > \text{for exactly one } i\leq n\}$.

Edit: I tried using the inequality $P(S_n \geq na) \geq P(S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon)P(X_n \geq n(a+\epsilon))$, but i don't know what to do next.

Comment: What is known about $a$? Is it positive?

Comment: @SungjinKim They don't specify anything about $a$.

Comment: In the context of the textbook, it seems that they are assuming $a>EX_1$. So, I think we have $a>0$ here.

Comment: @SungjinKim I think you're right. I added my answer which clearly only works if $a>0$.  The conclusion seems to fail for $a\leq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my answer after working on it for some time. A cleaner or shorter proof is welcome:

Let $F_n =\{X_i \geq n(a+\epsilon)\textrm{ for exactly one } i\leq n\}$ and note that $F_n = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^{n} G_i$, where $G_i$ is the event that the large element has index $i$. This gives us that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{P(S_n \geq na)}{nP(X_1\geq na)} &\geq \frac{P(F_n \cap \{S_n \geq na\})}{nP(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))} \\[0.5em]
&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(G_i \cap \{S_n \geq na\})}{nP(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))} \\[0.5em]
&=\frac{nP(G_1 \cap \{S_n \geq na\})}{nP(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))} \\[0.5em]
&=\frac{P(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))P\left(\left\{\max\limits_{i<n}X_i < n(a+\epsilon)\right\} \cap \{ S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon\} \right)}{P(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))} \\[0.5em]
&= P\left(\left\{\max\limits_{i<n}X_i < n(a+\epsilon)\right\} \cap \{ S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon\} \right)
\end{align*}
Since $EX_1 = 0$, then $E|X_1| <\infty$ and $nP(X_1 \geq n(a+\epsilon)) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. This gives us that:
$$P\left(\max\limits_{i<n}X_i \geq n(a+\epsilon)\right) \leq nP\left(X_1 > n(a+\epsilon)\right) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0. \ (*)$$
We have that $\liminf P\left(\left\{\max\limits_{i<n}X_i < n(a+\epsilon)\right\} \cap \{ S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon\} \right)$ is $1$ by the weak law of large numbers and $(*)$. This gives us the result.

Comment: Zero mean does not imply finite expection for the absolute value. Also, why would (*) be true?

Comment: Zero mean implies finite expectation of absolute value in the sense of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't think that true, but (*) is still an issue. Why is it true?

Comment: That is by Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\frac{P(S_n\geq na)}{nP(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))}\geq \frac{P(S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon \vert X_j<n(a+\epsilon) \text{ for all }j<n)P(F_n)}{nP(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))}. \ \ (1)
$$

Note that the conditional probability should be used due to lack of independence of "All $X_j <n(a+\epsilon)$" and "$S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon$".

Let $\alpha = P(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))$. Then $P(F_n)=n\alpha(1-\alpha)^{n-1}$, which gives (1) is at least
$$
P(S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon\vert X_j<n(a+\epsilon) \text{ for all }j<n)(1-\alpha)^{n-1}. 
$$
By Markov inequality, we have
$$
\alpha=P(X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon))\leq \frac{E(|X_1| I_{X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon)})}{n(a+\epsilon)}, \ \mathrm{and}
$$
$$
1-\alpha\geq 1-\frac{E(|X_1| I_{X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon)})}{n(a+\epsilon)}.
$$
Thus,
$$
1\geq (1-\alpha)^{n-1} \geq \left(1-\frac{E(|X_1| I_{X_1\geq n(a+\epsilon)})}{n(a+\epsilon)}\right)^{n-1} \rightarrow 1 \ \mathrm{as} \ n\rightarrow\infty.
$$
By Weak Law of Large Numbers (Textbook Theorems 2.2.12 and 2.2.14), $P(S_{n-1}\geq -n\epsilon\vert X_j<n(a+\epsilon) \text{ for all }j<n)\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The result follows.

Comment: I see how $P(S_n>na)\geq P(S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon,F_n)$ but how did you separate them as a product. They are not independent.

Comment: Let $F_n = \cup G_i$ where $G_i=\{X_i>n(a+\epsilon) \} \cap \{X_j\leq n(a+\epsilon) \text{ for all }j\neq i\}$. We have $\cup (G_i \cap \{\sum_{j\neq i} X_j >-n\epsilon\})\subseteq \{S_n>na\}$.

Comment: I am saying $P(S_n>na)\geq P(S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon,F_n)$ but that $P(S_n>na)\geq P(S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon)P(F_n)$is unclear as we don't have independence.

Comment: I am not starting with the first inequality you mentioned.

Comment: In my comment, $\cup (G_i \cap \{\sum_{j\neq i} X_j >-n\epsilon\})\subseteq \{S_n>na\}$ implies that $P(S_n>na)\geq \sum P(G_i)P(S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon)\geq P(S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon) \sum P(G_i) = P(S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon)P(F_n)$.

Comment: The lack of independence of $G_i$ and $S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon$ is corrected now. Thank you very much for pointing this error.

Comment: For the comments made by me, $S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon$ should be changed to $S_{n-1}>-n\epsilon \ | \ X_j\leq n(a+\epsilon) \text{ for all }j<n$.